# Linux timer in user-space and shared variables

Tags: linux, timer

I have a question about timer concept in user space.

I am trying to write an application code where I want to run a timer for some timeout value. In my application there are some shared variables which could be modified inside the timer handler or outside the timer context in the same application. If I implement a `mutex` to protect the shared variables and the application outside the timer is holding it and modifying the shared variables. In this time, the timer arrives and tries to grab the mutex, will it goto `sleep` till the application releases the mutex or will it deadlock?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a mutex is already locked, trying to lock it will block. If the timer is in the same thread as the one holding the lock, the thread will be blocked and it will never get to unlock the mutex, so you'll deadlock. If they're in different threads, only the timer thread will block, to the other thread will be able to continue and eventually unlock the mutex, which will allow the timer thread to continue.